# 3ds Max alternative for Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, graphics

Is there a good alternative to Autodesk's 3D modeling software [3ds Max](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/) that works on a Mac?

I like 3ds Max because it's very powerful and easy to use for someone who is not an expert in 3D modeling.

I tried Blender, but it was really hard to understand and control, and I found its commands to be very counter-intuitive.

Comment: Blender is not really "hard to understand", it uses different rules than Autodesk applications do, hence the similarity in Maya and Max. I'm just nitpicking on the phrasing here, just as "chocolate is disgusting" is different from "I hate chocolate" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autodesk's [Maya](http://usa.autodesk.com/maya/) has a Mac version.

I can't say I've used it, but it's quite popular.

Comment: Switched from 3dsmax to it. Its also Autodesk so the you can expect the same, if not better, level of support than 3dsmax.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as feature-laden as 3DS Max, but like Blender, [Art of Illusion](http://www.artofillusion.org/) is free and cross-platform, so it can't hurt to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was always a big, big fan of [Carrara](http://www.daz3d.com/i/software/carrara8) back when I was working with 3D software, and it looks as though the non-Pro version still packs a lot of punch.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Cinema4D](http://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d-studio/who-should-use-it.html) a try. Personally I find it even easier to understand than 3dsMax.

Answer (score 0):

I'd second Maya if you want a professional app that natively runs on a mac. I use it for architectural visualization.

However if you already own a 3DS Max Version why not run it on your mac via Bootcamp or Parallels. Autodesk even supports this kind of usage of their software.

http://usa.autodesk.com/products/mac-compatible-products

A license of parallels + windows might be cheeper than spending the extra money (and time training) on a new software.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Archicad, is for Architecture but it has a powerful tool called morph that works just fine to me, then you can export the file to 3ds or c4d. You should give a try with that one.